# Java new constructor not working

Tags: java

I have class Point (in Java, features: int x, int y) with simple constructor: `public Point {this.x = x; this.y = y;}`, x & y - the point's coordinates. It's working. In the same package I add new class Segment (features: Point left, Point right) with constructor: `public Segment(int leftX,int leftY,int rightX,int rightY) {...}` (four coordinates for left & right points). I try to create this constructor, but it's not work. What must be instead of {...}?

My code :

```
class Point1 {
    private final int _x, _y;

    public Point1(int x, int y) {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }
}

class Segment {
    private Point1 _poLeft, _poRight;

    public Segment(int leftX, int leftY, int rightX, int rightY) {}
}
```

Comment: And What error you are getting?

Comment: public class Point1 
{
 private int _x, _y;
 public Point1(int x, int y)
 {
  _x = x;
  _y = y;
 }

Comment: If this is the whole class, you're missing a `}` that closes the class definition.

Comment: @IgalRozman Please use the edit button under the question to add requested details - comments isn't a good place for it

Comment: @kocko -Ya, I added that (assuming its a typo) :)

Comment: public class Segment {
 
 private Point1 _poLeft, _poRight;
 
 public Segment(int leftX,int leftY,int rightX,int rightY)
 {---)

Comment: NullPointerException

Comment: @IgalRozman  - Please add your code to the *question* itself and not in comments

Comment: What's constructor must be to public class Segment ?

Comment: class Segment : Point1 a,b; should be better way

Answer (score 0):

the Question is not in perfect form and lacked main code, so i had to make some assumptions with what was posted

---

java.awt.Point looked a better option so i used it , *made explicit mention of package to avoid confusion*

> public class Point
> extends Point2D
> implements Serializable
>
> **A point representing a location in (x,y) coordinate space, specified in integer precision**.

```
class SegmentofPoints {
    java.awt.Point aPoint;
    java.awt.Point bPoint;

    public SegmentofPoints(Point aPoint, Point bPoint) {
        this.aPoint = aPoint;
        this.bPoint = bPoint;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.awt.Point aPoint;
        java.awt.Point bPoint;

        aPoint = new Point(1, 0);
        bPoint = new Point(2, 1);

        SegmentofPoints segment = new SegmentofPoints(aPoint, bPoint);
        System.out.println(segment.aPoint.toString() + " & "
                + segment.bPoint.toString());
    }
}
```

---

> output
>
> java.awt.Point[x=1,y=0] & java.awt.Point[x=2,y=1]

Comment: Thanks for all. I forgot to create new objects and gave exception :((

Answer (score 0):

You can have several constructors in your class, depending on how you intend to build it. For instance, here I define 2 constructors, one from coordinates and the other from already existing `Point` instances:

```
public class Segment { 
   private Point1 left, right; 

   public Segment(int leftX, int leftY, int rightX, int rightY) {
      left = new Point1(leftX, leftY);
      right = new Point1(rightX, rightY);
   }

   public Segment(Point1 left, Point1 right) {
      this.left = left;
      this.right = right;
   }
}
```

In Java, you can call a constructor from another one. This can help keep consistency in the class. The above code would be:

```
public class Segment { 
   private Point1 left, right; 

   public Segment(Point1 left, Point1 right) {
      this.left = left;
      this.right = right;
   }

   public Segment(int leftX, int leftY, int rightX, int rightY) {
      // call the constructor above with freshly created Points
      this(new Point1(leftX, leftY), new Point1(rightX, rightY));
   }    
}
```